# Azure Scheduler can't reach my http handler

Tags: handler, azure-mobile-services

I created an asp Http Handler. Deployed it to Azure. This handler should be called from Azure Mobile services scheduler. When the scheduler is sending post to the handler I got an 404 error, but when I call the same handler from my local Node.js command prompt everything is ok. What can cause this? Are there any restrictions in Azure?

Comment: May this problem be connected not with handler address but with missing "require('request');" this Request module?

Comment: Can you post some code of what you're doing?